# How to checksum specifc table in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, checksum

In MySQL I can get the checksum of the table like:

```
CHECKSUM TABLE 'TableName'
```

How can I calculate check sum of the table in SQLite? Are there any alternatives?

EDIT:
Will the SQLite checksum(calculated manually) be equal to MySQL checksum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite does not have a built-in checksum feature.

You could either read all the data from the table and calculate a hash over the data yourself, or install triggers on every table that update a table checksum.

Comment: Do the SQLite checksum(calculated manually) will be equal to MySQL checksum?

Comment: That depends on whether you use the same checksumming algorithm in your code.